# Position Changes Automatically

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a simple change on my project, which is lowering my characters position. But it automatically resets itself to "1.98" whenever I start it. I am pretty sure that I do not change it thourgh my scripts. Any ideas?[image: unity]

Comment: maybe it is set in the script

Comment: Not really. I've found that Character Controller height changes the gap between the plane and the character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to set position automatically.

1. script
2. animation
3. collider with rigidbody.

I hope it will work.